# Problema com if em JAVA condição errada

Tags: java

```
public class Atividade_01 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    final double PI = 3.1415;

    String R = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o raio: ");

    Float raio = Float.parseFloat(R);
    double area = PI*(raio*raio);
    int areaint = (int)area;
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"A area é: "+areaint);
    
    if (areaint <= 1000) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Será preciso 1 salva-vidas!");
    }
    if ((areaint >= 1001)||(areaint <=10000)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Será preciso 2 salva-vidas!");
    }
    if ((areaint >= 10001) ||(areaint <= 100000)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Será preciso 3 salva-vidas!");
    }
    if (areaint >= 100001) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Será preciso 4 salva-vidas!");
    }     
}
```

}

Bom, este é meu código, preciso realizar a determinação de quantos salva-vidas precisaram ficar na região de acordo com o tamanho da área do raio. Quando é colocado um valor alto que resulte uma área grande ele fica preso no segundo if (raio = 1000, área = 314 mil por exemplo) e quando é colocado um valor baixo é passado pelos 3 primeiros if's (raio = 2 , área = 12 por exemplo). Agradeceria muito se alguém puder me ajudar a entender por que está dando esse erro.

Comment: As condições deveriam usar `&&` e não `||`

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!!

Comment: Eu estou votando para fechar esta pergunta porque foi respondida nos comentários

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está utilizando o operador OU (`||`) ao invés do operador E (`&&`), de qualquer forma, acredito que seria interessante utilizar else if nesse caso, evitando várias verificações desnecessárias, desse jeito:

```
if (areaint <= 1000) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Será preciso 1 salva-vidas!");
} else if (areaint <= 10000) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Será preciso 2 salva-vidas!");
} else if (areaint <= 100000) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Será preciso 3 salva-vidas!");
} else if (areaint >= 100001) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Será preciso 4 salva-vidas!");
}
```